# how to disable a button if a field contains a number? VUE JS

Tags: vue.js

I would like to ask on how to disable a button when a field contains a number?
my example code would be:

```
disabledSubmitButton() {
  return this.$v.$error ||
    this.firstName === '' ||
    this.lastName === '' ||
    this.birthDate === '' ||
    this.province === '' ||
    this.$v.birthDate.$error ||
    this.city === '' ||
    this.nationality === '' ||
    this.mobileNumber === ''
}
```

what happen here is that it will disable the button if this statements are encountered. what should i add? thank you. ps. i cant use a type or v-on: keypress due to pwa is running on mobile devices, using v-on keypress only works on browsers. please help thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with computed propertie.

```js
new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data: {
      input: ""
   },
   computed: {
      disabled() {
         return /\d/.test(this.input)
      }
   }
})
```

```css
button {
   background: none;
   border: none;
   border:1px solid #dadada;
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   background: lightgrey !important;
   color: grey !Important;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <input v-model="input" />
   <button :class="{ disabled }">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the complete information you have given, im new to JScript.

Answer (score 1):

In order to check if a string contains a number, you can do this:

```js
function containsNumber(str) {
     return /\d/.test(str);
}

console.log(containsNumber("a"));
console.log(containsNumber("a1"));
```